# How to "Portal" a mounted react component into another?

Tags: reactjs

Goal:

iFrame loads web content in Component A

portal iFrame to component B

The iFrame should not be mounted as a new instance, and all the iFrame's state from comp A to comp B, and vice versa.

Currently, using react portal and other portal libs, it just takes in a component, that mounts it into the desired component.

I want the memory/state to persist during portaling

"Portaling" in this case means I am sending a node from one component to another, and NOT mounting a NEW instance of the component. (Please do not attempt to use css workarounds!)

To know if it is working, navigate around in iFrame in component A, and when it is "portal'ed" into component B, it should have the same state.

As for unmounting it when it is actually no longer in use, we can have a helper getComponentProxy("component-id").destroy().

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code? It’s not clear in your question how the code is structured.

Comment: This is not an issue with portaling. My attempt has been using portals, which I believe is behaving correctly, ie: mounting a new instance of a component. The implementation is up to you.

Comment: What does "portal" mean here? (and please explain that in the post, not in a comment). Are you talking about https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal (in which case, please show code to demonstrate what you've come up with so far). Do you just want the iframe node moved from one DOM node to another DOM node, without React going "this DOM node isn't managed by me, I am going to delete it"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans edited

Comment: I can't say this is much clearer: please give the [posting guidlines](/help/how-to-ask) a re-read, and edit your post to be a little more formal: (1) what did you set it to achieve, (2) what code did you write for that, (3) talk about why you wrote _that_ specific code, (4) talk about what the code does and how that's not what you expected, and (5) talk about what you already did in terms of debugging and (re)searching/alternate attempts. And in step (2), of course, remember to show a [mcve] because it's simply unclear whether you're an expert on createPortal, or just "doing it wrong(tm)".

Comment: Dan Abramov touched on this in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12247#issuecomment-486378549) a while back. You can read through the issue and some of it might not be relevent now (being from 2019) but it sounds like Dan's suggestion would work for what you are attempting to achieve. You could attempt to create a sort of "node manager" as Dan suggests, the node manager would handle DOM node movement outside of react (meaning no remount) and you could then use the ref provided by the manager in a portal, making the rest of the code just React.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your requirements.

So to access the parent node, you can use: `window.parent.document.getElementById('portal')`. Then you can mount your component to the node:

```
import {createPortal} from 'react-dom'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

const Welcome = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('Guest')

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setUserName('Bob'), 3000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <p>Hello {userName}!</p>
  )
}


createPortal(
  <Welcome/>, 
  window.parent.document.getElementById('portal'),
)
```

For communication (share state) between iframe and parent document, you can use:

```js
// send object (json) from iframe
window.parent.postMessage({hello: 'world!'}, "*")


// add listener on parent document to get data from iframe:
window.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log(event.data)
}, false)
```